# How to summarize property values in Gremlin?

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin, rexster

I'm quite new to Gremlin and have now spent hours trying to figure out how to calculate the values for a given property in all my vertices.

This

```
g.V('containerName','MyContainer').outE.inV.'(0)Probability'
```

gives me:

```
 {"results":[" 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":15.894908}
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is:

1. How can I convert the strings in the list to integer? I've tried...

   ```
   g.V('containerName','CvsRisk').outE.inV.'(0)Probability'.toInteger()
   ```

   ..., but it does not work.
2. How to summarize all the values in the list, thus 3+3+...+3, not using count.

Comment: Do you mean "sum-up" with "summarize"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple groovy:

```
l = [" 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"," 3"]
s = 0; l.each{s+=it.toInteger()}
s
==>27
```

Comment: simpler groovy `l*.toInteger()` and `l*.toInteger().sum()`

Comment: Thank you once again Faber :)